# Facebook Android 3.0 blank login page in all examples

Tags: android, facebook

Trying FB android 3.0 SDK on emulator. Tried to run different examples but all of them stuck on blank webview. Below is logact when I launch FriendPickerSampleActivity.

LOGCAT:

```
    03-17 10:56:12.653: D/FacebookSDK.WebDialog(457): Webview loading URL:   https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?type=user_agent&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&display=touch&client_id=370546396320150
```

It's been 2 days tried multiple options but all in vain. any Help?

I have never installed or used FB on emulator ever. And here blank means all white.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Facebook API Shows White Blank Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471493/android-facebook-api-shows-white-blank-page)

Answer (score 2):

Change the sandbox option to disable. ( Settings -> Basic Info )

Comment: Worked! surprisingly did the job. dont understand why but it did the magic!!

Answer (score 0):

As I answered here [Android Facebook API Shows White Blank Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471493/android-facebook-api-shows-white-blank-page)

Adding

webView.resumeTimers();

at the end of com.facebook.widget.WebDialog.setUpWebView() worked for me.(Facebook SDK 3.0+)