# Android Facebook API Shows White Blank Page

Tags: android

I am using Android Facebook API but when I click on login button of Facebook it opens the white screen blank just as the image attached. Please suggest some solutions to me.

[image]

```
public void facebookLogin(FacebookLoginHandller target) {
        try {
            this.superLocal = target;

            if (facebook == null) {
                facebook = new Facebook(APPID);
            }

            if (facebook.isSessionValid()) {
                superLocal.loginStatus(1);
            } else {
                facebook.authorize(Activity.this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener(new FacebookLoginHandller() {

                    @Override
                    public void loginStatus(int status) {

                        if (status == 1) {
                            superLocal.loginStatus(1);
                        }
                    }
                }));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post some code at least.

Answer (score 4):

Adding

```
webView.resumeTimers();
```

at the end of com.facebook.widget.WebDialog.setUpWebView() worked for me.(Facebook SDK 3.0+)

Answer (score 2):

Steps to solve this issue

Open your facebook library ( com.facebook.android) which is added as library

Open FaceBook.java class

In that we will found private static final int DEFAULT_AUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE = 32665.

You should change to DEFAULT_AUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE to -1

Now save it and clean and build both library and your application

**Note :**

this blank screen appear only for latest versions only .

Comment: I have tried this too .....:) Thanks for your help